# a bit of difference between null and space

Tags: null

I was just reading this quote

> And don't tell me there isn't one bit of difference between null and
>   space, because that's exactly how much difference there is.  :-)

by Larry wall
Can anyone tell me what's the `bit` of difference he meant here between space and `null`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

null is binary 00000000, space is 00100000.

I suppose that's the bit being referred to.

Comment: Yeah it is actually a quite funny qoute if you look at it ^^